# SonataAdminBundle and OneToOne relationship

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I have a OneToOne relationship between `Page` and `SuperGridContent`:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SuperGridContent", mappedBy="page", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $super_grid;

    //...
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="super_grid_content")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class SuperGridContent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="super_grid")
     */
    private $page;

    //...
}
```

Then in the page admin class I have:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use AppBundle\Entity\Page;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType;

class PageAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('super_grid', ModelType::class, [
                'label' => 'Super Grid',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            // ...
        ;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that when I create or edit a `Page`, the `super_grid` field is a select tag with all existing `SuperGridContent` as options. Even when they already have a `Page` relationship. If I select one of those, of course it fails, because the relationship is suposed to be unique.

Am I missing something or is there a way Sonata could handle it?

I'm using SonataAdminBundle 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you problem, I think you could use Symfony Entity Type instead of the Model Type as stated in Sonata [documentation](https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/getting_started/the_form_view/#using-the-entity-type).

But I also think that your life would be much easier if you inverted the ownership of the OneToOne relationship. In your example `SuperGridContent` is owning the relationship so when you want to update the `super_grid` of a `Page` you might run into a constraint violation. If you change `inversedBy` to `mappedBy` in the `SuperGridContent` class and `mappedBy` to `inversedBy` in the `Page` class (+ if you regenerate your tables and make sure the cascading logic fits your needs) you should be OK.

If I understand well, you want any new `Page` to have only the available `super_grid`s as choices and any existing `Page` to have its current `super_grid` + all the available `super_grid`s as choices.

Then something like the following would do the job (careful that I am using Symfony 4.4, there might be slight syntax differences with your implementation):

```php
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
//use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use App\Entity\Page;
use App\Entity\SuperGridContent;


final class PageAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form): void
    {
        $subject = $this->getSubject();

        if($subject->getId()){
            $form
            ->add('super_grid', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SuperGridContent::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($subject) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->leftjoin('s.page', 'p')
                        ->where('p.super_grid is null')
                        ->orWhere('p = :my_page')
                        ->setParameter('my_page', $subject)
                        ;
                },
            ]);
        }
        else{
            $form
            ->add('super_grid', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SuperGridContent::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->leftjoin('s.page', 'p')
                        ->where('p.super_grid is null')
                        ;
                },
            ]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not return the current super_grid if set

Comment: I just change the answer so it fits better your needs